# Simultaneous accesses to 0x14572f2a0, but modification requires exclusive access

Tags: swift

I am following example code from the book "Design Patterns in Swift 5". The example is for the section on the State Pattern.

I am getting a memory access error: "Simultaneous accesses to 0x14572f2a0, but modification requires exclusive access." when I try to run the code.

I am not sure what's going on... Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
import Foundation

public final class ATM {
    
    fileprivate var state: ATMState = IdleState()
    
    public func enter(pin: String) {
        state = EnterPinState(context: self)
        state.validate(pin: pin)
    }
    
    public func withdraw(amount: Float) -> Bool {
        return state.withdraw(amount: amount)
    }
}

fileprivate protocol ATMState {
    func validate(pin: String)
    mutating func withdraw(amount: Float) -> Bool
    func transactionCompleted(success:Bool)
}

extension ATMState {
    func validate(pin:String) {
        print("not implemented")
    }
    mutating func withdraw(amount: Float) -> Bool {
        print("not implemented")
        return false
    }
    func transactionCompleted(success:Bool) {
        print("not implemented")
    }
}

fileprivate struct IdleState: ATMState {
    
}

fileprivate struct EnterPinState: ATMState {
    
    let context: ATM
    
    func validate(pin: String) {
        guard pin == "1234" else {
            print("wrong pin")
            context.state = TransactionCompleteState(context:context)
            context.state.transactionCompleted(success: false)
            return
        }
        print("pin ok")
        context.state = WithdrawState(context: context)
    }
}

fileprivate struct TransactionCompleteState: ATMState {
    let context: ATM
    
    func transactionCompleted(success: Bool) {
        var statusMessage = success ? "Transaction complete..." : "Transaction failed..."
        print(statusMessage)
        context.state = IdleState()
    }
}

fileprivate struct WithdrawState: ATMState {
    var context: ATM
    var availableFunds: Float = 1000
    
    init(context: ATM) {
        self.context = context
    }
    
    mutating func withdraw(amount: Float) -> Bool {
        print("Withdraw $\(amount)")
        guard amount > 0 && availableFunds >= amount else {
            print("invalid")
            context.state = TransactionCompleteState(context: context)
            context.state.transactionCompleted(success: false)
            return false
        }
        availableFunds -= amount
        context.state = TransactionCompleteState(context: context)
        context.state.transactionCompleted(success: true)
        return true
    }
}

let atm = ATM()
atm.enter(pin:"1234")
atm.withdraw(amount: 10)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you get for testing the code in a playground — there's no debugger! If you try that code in a real app, the debugger tells you exactly what the problem is.

The problem is here:

```
public func withdraw(amount: Float) -> Bool {
    return state.withdraw(amount: amount) // <-- *
}
```

The withdraw state's `withdraw` method sets the `state` property of its `context`, which is this ATM instance. So the call to `state.withdraw` means that we both *mutate* this ATM's state value directly, by replacing it with a different state object, *and* call its mutating *method* `withdraw`, in a single move. You can't do that, because the double mutation, to a property of the struct and to a reference to the struct as a whole, is incoherent. You have to proceed in stages, like this:

```
public func withdraw(amount: Float) -> Bool {
    // fetch
    var theState = self.state
    // mutate
    return theState.withdraw(amount: amount)
}
```

The alternative would be to make all of the state types *classes* instead of structs. A class, unlike a struct, is mutable in place. That would require considerably more rewriting, however, so that is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: OP, please note slight correction; sorry about that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this is an access violation? I don't see it. We're calling a mutating function on an instance member. "that we both fetch state and call its mutating method withdraw" IDK what precisely you mean by "fetch", and how is it different from what's done in `var theState = self.state`?

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right, I'll fix that. Thanks for keeping me honest.

Comment: Wasn't my intention, and sorry to bust your nuts, but I still don't get it. Where is `state` being "replaced"?

Comment: In the withdraw state's `withdraw` function: `context.state =...` The "deep" cause of the whole thing is the use of `context` to point back to the owner of this struct. Look at how the pattern works: every call to a state method is allowed to replace the state with a different state representing the next stage of the ATM's being. It's a cool pattern but it runs into the access violation problem.

Comment: Oh I get it. So actually, the `withdraw` isn't malformed as-is (hence, no static warning from the compiler), but calling it as part of an expression assigned to `context` is the issue. Is that correct?

Comment: Yepper, I hope my rewrite has captured that. Feel free to edit if you think you can do better. :) As you rightly suggest, the compiler doesn't reason so far ahead as to know that `context.state` will in fact be `self` at runtime.

Comment: I've made an edit, can you let me know what you think? Not married to it, but I think it breaks it down in a bit more detail

Comment: Sorry, rolled it back. This has nothing to do with duration or time. Everything happens in some order, but the order is not known. The point is that the combination of the two mutating accesses, mutating the struct and mutating the reference to it, has an undefined outcome. I think my answer already says that. If you want to write another answer I'll upvote it.

Comment: "This has nothing to do with duration or time." Not in wall-clock time, but yes, it actually does. What constitutes an "access" has a defined start/end point. See: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md#instantaneous-and-non-instantaneous-accesses I'm busy now but I'll write something up later